# Dancer Hooks on a per-request method basis?

Tags: perl, crud, dancer

I'm working on a CRUD application using Dancer. One of the things I need to do is check a user is authorized to perform POST (create) and PUT (update) / DELETE (remove) operations.

I've read up on `before` hooks in the Dancer documentation, but have been unable to figure out the best way to do varying types of authorization.

For a POST operation, all I want to do is check that a valid API key has been submitted with the request, but for a PUT/DELETE operation, I want to check that the API key submitted matches the user who is attached to the record to be updated or deleted.

I understand how to do the logic behind checking the API keys, but I'm wondering if hooks (or something else) would allow me to call that logic without having to add the same boilerplate function call to every single PUT/POST/DELETE function on every route.

Answer (score 3):

like I told the poster on IRC, I think a combination of https://metacpan.org/pod/Dancer#request (the Dancer request object) and its HTTP verbs querying things should do the trick. See for example: https://metacpan.org/pod/Dancer::Request#is_post .

I'm not sure if it's a very elegant solution, but I think it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another take on this issue, based on experience:

Since Dancer has not had the opportunity to parse your input parameters when the 'before' hook executes, you may not have a consistent way to read in your authentication credentials, if your application allows them to be provided in a variety of ways.

In particular, if you're using input parameters to pass a nonce to prevent CSRF attacks (which you should definitely consider!), you won't have a consistent way to obtain that nonce.  You could do your own mini-parameter-parsing within 'before', but that could be messy too.

I ran into this problem when I worked on an application some time ago, and remember having to add the dreaded boilerplate authentication function to every PUT/POST/DELETE route.  Then, if you're doing that, it becomes irrelevant to check request->is_post because you're already deciding whether to place the boilerplate authentication function within the route.

Answer (score -1):

I haven't tried this yet, but it may be possible to handle the pre-requisite action in your Route base class, then pass upon success. This will leave your specific packages to handle the request as normal once your base class has verified authentication.

> An action can choose not to serve the current request and ask Dancer to process the request with the next matching route. This is done with the pass keyword, like in the following example

```
get '/say/:word' => sub {
return pass if (params->{word} =~ /^\d+$/);
"I say a word: ".params->{word};
};

get '/say/:number' => sub {
    "I say a number: ".params->{number};
};
```